# How to visualizing .stp file in 3d using OpenCascade?

Tags: cad, step, opencascade

I have read the .stp files using OpenCascade library, but I am not able to visualize it. How to use OpenCascade library to visualize (render) the .stp file.

Answer (score 2):

Open CASCADE is shipped with a Qt sample named "IESample". It demonstrates how to import and export STEP and IGES files and how to visualize them. The method `Translate::displayShSequence(...)` in Translate.cxx adds shapes to an interactive context and updates the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

F3D is using OpenCascade to visualize .stp files, you can take a look at:

https://github.com/f3d-app/f3d/